# Any info on this SDL_CreateWindow error on windows?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, sdl, vulkan

Using SDL to create window for rendering engine that uses Vulkan. Following [this](https://github.com/vblanco20-1/vulkan-guide/blob/all-chapters/) code. Following is the snippet of interest:

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

SDL_WindowFlags window_flags = (SDL_WindowFlags)(SDL_WINDOW_VULKAN);

_window = SDL_CreateWindow(
    "Vulkan Engine",
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
    _windowExtent.width,
    _windowExtent.height,
    window_flags
);
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2019. Saw this error, built SDL from source as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50571213/10935149) suggested Vulkan flag may not have been enables in the posted binaries. Still, getting error on window creation. Line by line debugging points to this as the line where things break:

```
return CallWindowProc(data->wndproc, hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
```

in [SDL_windowsevents.c](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/main/src/video/windows/SDL_windowsevents.c).

Exception:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFF584A4F8E (ntdll.dll) in GraphicsModel.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack 
overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000ED25003FB8).
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFF584A4F8E (ntdll.dll) in GraphicsModel.exe: 0xC000041D: An unhandled exception was encountered during a user callback.
```

Let me know if I should paste the full stacktrace. Can't figure out what's the cause, any help would be great!

Edit: Callstack (confirms infinite recursion)

```
    ntdll.dll!00007ffb84e44f8e()    Unknown
    user32.dll!00007ffb83345aa4()   Unknown
    user32.dll!00007ffb833458ee()   Unknown
    mfc140ud.dll!00007ffaf0091b05() Unknown
    user32.dll!00007ffb83345c1d()   Unknown
    user32.dll!00007ffb833458ee()   Unknown
    SDL2.dll!0000000075e4e7d0() Unknown
    user32.dll!00007ffb83345c1d()   Unknown
    user32.dll!00007ffb833458ee()   Unknown
    mfc140ud.dll!00007ffaf0091b05() Unknown
    user32.dll!00007ffb83345c1d()   Unknown
    user32.dll!00007ffb833458ee()   Unknown



    THIS BLOCK REPEATS 'n' times
    ---------------------------------------

    SDL2.dll!0000000075e4e7d0() Unknown
    user32.dll!00007ffb83345c1d()   Unknown
    user32.dll!00007ffb833458ee()   Unknown
    mfc140ud.dll!00007ffaf0091b05() Unknown
    user32.dll!00007ffb83345c1d()   Unknown
    user32.dll!00007ffb833458ee()   Unknown

    ---------------------------------------


    SDL2.dll!0000000075e4e7d0() Unknown
    user32.dll!00007ffb83345c1d()   Unknown
    user32.dll!00007ffb833457ec()   Unknown
    user32.dll!00007ffb83354432()   Unknown
>   ntdll.dll!00007ffb84ec0b04()    Unknown
    win32u.dll!00007ffb82ea1524()   Unknown
    SDL2.dll!0000000075e58ebe() Unknown
    SDL2.dll!0000000075e2172d() Unknown
    GraphicsModel.exe!VulkanEngine::init() Line 59  C++
    GraphicsModel.exe!CMainFrame::OnCreate(tagCREATESTRUCTW * lpCreateStruct) Line 67   C++
    [External Code] 
    GraphicsModel.exe!CGraphicsModelApp::InitInstance() Line 106    C++
    [External Code] 
    GraphicsModel.exe!wWinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance, HINSTANCE__ * hPrevInstance, wchar_t * lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) Line 26 C++
    [External Code]
```

Comment: Attach a debugger and inspect the callstack at the time of the stack overflow. Most likely you have an infinite recursion in your custom window procedure. This isn't answerable without a [mcve].

Comment: If you get stack overflow in `CallWindowProc`, you are probably hitting infinite recursion.

Comment: thanks guys, the window is directly being created by SDL, so I don't think I've much control over the call, posting in SDL specific forums/github looks like a better option.

Comment: Similar issue https://github.com/scp-fs2open/fs2open.github.com/issues/674

Comment: Just submitted issue: https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/issues/4205

Comment: To make the callstacks more useful you should load debug symbols. In Visual Studio you can right-click any stack frame and select *Load symbols...*. Consult the manual for other debuggers to get symbol information.

Comment: Aso worth mentioning is test itself should really be minimal, and 3 first stack entries are suggesting it isn't. Make a single main function with code in question and nothing else, not vast class hierarchy. Any extra code that we don't see theoretically could be an issue.

Comment: Was using the code in an MFC application. Have a theory that this might have happened due to a window instance already being used by the application. 
Simple window creation is working in a solitary project which just creates this SDL window(https://github.com/naivisoftware/vulkansdldemo).